# How to update PHP to > 5.5 via SSH?

Tags: php, laravel, ssh, deployment, composer-php

I am going to deploy my laravel project to server

but i found the server is using PHP version 5.3

and the requirement of laravel 5.2 needs >5.5

so do you know how to update it?

Before I just uploaded my whole laravel project to my server via FileZilla, but it not work.

Comment: In what environment? What operating system? Shared hosting or VPS?

Comment: how to check the OS with ssh?

Comment: That depends… are you using shared hosting? If so, you probably don't have control over the PHP version you are using. You should probably refer to your host's documentation.

Comment: since the host is from my friend, and I think she has rent a server, so I can have full access for the host.

Comment: Can you ask your friend for help? If she is providing hosting for you she probably knows what OS she is running, and might even have preferences about how to install and upgrade PHP.